# Применимость t-теста, расчет уровня значимости

Tags: r, rstudio

У индейцев из племени Пима высокая частота заболеваний диабетом второго типа. В датасете Pima.tr из пакета MASS приведены данные анализов крови для 200 человек из этого племени (это случайная выборка 21 летних индейцев, живущих в районе г.Феникс в Аризоне). Различается ли концентрация глюкозы в крови у больных диабетом и здоровых людей?

Выполняются ли условия применимости t-теста для этих данных?

Сохраните результаты теста в переменную, а затем экстрагируйте из нее значение t-статистики, число степеней свободы и уровень значимости.

Данные уже загружены в переменную Pima.tr. Все переменные, которые необходимо создать, перечислены в окне кода.

```
#Выполняются ли условия применимости t-теста? (TRUE - да, FALSE - нет) 
can_use_t_test <- 
# t-тест
t_test_results <- 
# Значение t-статистики
t_val <- 
# Число степеней свободы
d_f <- 
# Уровень значимости
p_val <-
```

Comment: Все что вы хотели знать о диабете но стеснялись спросить :) https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/553862/

Comment: отличное задание. но вопрос-то в чём?